# Filter on Datatable using jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am trying to implement excel type filter on data table similar to the following code. but the problem is this code give duplicates values in the search filter and it eliminates based on row index.

This also does not handle null cases and adds empty checkbox in the filter.

please let me know how we can eliminate duplicates and null cases.

[Used code from this URL](http://embed.plnkr.co/w4z9A4/)

```js
// Code goes here



var arrayMap = {};

function showFilterOption(tdObject){
  var filterGrid = $(tdObject).find(".filter");
  
  if (filterGrid.is(":visible")){
    filterGrid.hide();
    return;
  }
  
  $(".filter").hide();
  

  
  var index = 0;
  filterGrid.empty();
  var allSelected = true;
  filterGrid.append('<div><input id="all" type="checkbox" checked>Select All</div>');
  
  var $rows = $(tdObject).parents("table").find("tbody tr");
  
  
  $rows.each(function(ind, ele){
    var currentTd = $(ele).children()[$(tdObject).attr("index")];
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("grid-item")
    var str = $(ele).is(":visible") ? 'checked' : '';
    if ($(ele).is(":hidden")){
      allSelected = false;
    }
    div.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" '+str+' >'+currentTd.innerHTML;
    filterGrid.append(div);
    arrayMap[index] = ele;
    index++;
  });
  
  if (!allSelected){
    filterGrid.find("#all").removeAttr("checked");
  }
  
  filterGrid.append('<div><input id="close" type="button" value="Close"/><input id="ok" type="button" value="Ok"/></div>');
  filterGrid.show();
   
  
  $gridItems.click(function(event){
    var chk = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
    $(chk).prop("checked",!$(chk).is(":checked"));
  });
  
  $all.change(function(){
    var chked = $(this).is(":checked");
    filterGrid.find(".grid-item [type='checkbox']").prop("checked",chked);
  })
  
  filterGrid.click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  return filterGrid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.0.3" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table class="grid">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td index=0>Name
            <div class="filter"></div>
          </td>
          <td index=1>Address  
            <div class="filter"></div>
            </td>
          <td index=2>City
            <div class="filter"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>first</td>
          <td>first add</td>
          <td>SDF dfd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>second</td>
          <td>second add</td>
          <td>SDF dfd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>third</td>
          <td>third add</td>
          <td>SDF dfd</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to the specific problem you've got by following the guidelines how to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is how a question should be asked: An explanation of the desired functionality, a description of the error, the relevant code used and a demonstrative plunkr.

Answer (score 1):

you need to just add code for make unique your list of filter checkbox something like my file.just replace your js file with mine Hope it is same as you want

```js
// Code goes here

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $(".grid thead td").click(function(){
      showFilterOption(this);
    });
    
});

var arrayMap = {};

function showFilterOption(tdObject){
  var filterGrid = $(tdObject).find(".filter");
  
  if (filterGrid.is(":visible")){
    filterGrid.hide();
    return;
  }
  
  $(".filter").hide();
  
  var index = 0;
  filterGrid.empty();
  var allSelected = true;
  filterGrid.append('<div><input id="all" type="checkbox" checked>Select All</div>');
  
  var $rows = $(tdObject).parents("table").find("tbody tr");
  
  var uniqueArr =[];
  $rows.each(function(ind, ele){
    var currentTd = $(ele).children()[$(tdObject).attr("index")];
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("grid-item")
    var str = $(ele).is(":visible") ? 'checked' : '';
    if ($(ele).is(":hidden")){
      allSelected = false;
    }
    div.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" '+str+' >'+currentTd.innerHTML;
    if(!uniqueArr.includes(currentTd.innerHTML)){
      uniqueArr.push(currentTd.innerHTML);
      filterGrid.append(div);
    }
    arrayMap[index] = ele;
    index++;
  });
  
  if (!allSelected){
    filterGrid.find("#all").removeAttr("checked");
  }
  
  filterGrid.append('<div><input id="close" type="button" value="Close"/><input id="ok" type="button" value="Ok"/></div>');
  filterGrid.show();
  
  var $closeBtn = filterGrid.find("#close");
  var $okBtn = filterGrid.find("#ok");
  var $checkElems = filterGrid.find("input[type='checkbox']");
  var $gridItems = filterGrid.find(".grid-item");
  var $all = filterGrid.find("#all");
  
  $closeBtn.click(function(){
    filterGrid.hide();
    return false;
  });
  
  $okBtn.click(function(){
    filterGrid.find(".grid-item").each(function(ind,ele){
      if ($(ele).find("input").is(":checked")){
        $(arrayMap[ind]).show();
      }else{
        $(arrayMap[ind]).hide();
      }
    });
    filterGrid.hide();
    return false;
  });
  
  $checkElems.click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  $gridItems.click(function(event){
    var chk = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
    $(chk).prop("checked",!$(chk).is(":checked"));
  });
  
  $all.change(function(){
    var chked = $(this).is(":checked");
    filterGrid.find(".grid-item [type='checkbox']").prop("checked",chked);
  })
  
  filterGrid.click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  return filterGrid;
}
```